# How to have one liner code for creating and updating map entries?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap, one-liner

In C++, when using maps, one of the ways we can quickly create a new entry and update a map at the same time is by simply doing something like:

```
dict[key]+=1;
```

This allows you to bypass checking to see if a particular key already exists, and then creating an if else statement for it.

I was wondering if there was something similar for Java, especially for a put command.

At present I am stuck using two separate put statements. Trying to use a put statement and combining an addition statement with the value parameter hasn't worked.

Comment: Does "update" mean only increment like your example? If not, what other types of updates are possible in the context of your question.

Comment: @Bohemian In this case its explicitly for incrementing.

Answer (score 3):

Java Map has several related methods, depending on what you need.
Probably the most generic method is [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-). Your example would translate to:

```
dict.merge(
    key, 
    1, // Set this value if the key didn't exist yet
    (oldValue, value) -> oldValue + value // Add value to old value if the key already existed
);
```

In one line:

```
dict.merge(key, 1, (val, increment) -> val + increment);
```

There are also a few simpler methods for other purposes, e.g. [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-).

Answer (score 0):

In c++ when the key is not present in the map, the key, value pair gets added and its value is by default set to 0 [[Default value in map](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-values-in-a-map-in-c-stl/)], but in Java when the key is not found it returns null.

But it is possible to bypass the checking by setting the default return value to 0,

```
int key = 2;
HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
hm.put(key, hm.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
```

[HashMap_doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-)

Comment: It is possible. See the `merge()` method of Map.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to your situation is:

```
Map<KeyType, AtomicInteger> myMap = new HashMap<>();

newValue = myMap.computeIfAbsent(key, x -> new AtomicInteger()).incrementAndGet();
```